# How to click at an element by the CSS code using Protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I've been trying to click at the element using CSS Selector but it doesn't work:

```
<button _ngcontent-c16="" class="btn btn-flat btn-no-text btn-kebab-view">
         <i _ngcontent-c16="" class="zmdi zmdi-more-vert"></i>
</button>
```

I'm trying:

```
element.all(by.css('.btn .btn-flat .btn-no-text .btn-kebab-view')).first().click();
```

Protractor gives me error:

> Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but
>   there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, .btn
>   .btn-flat .btn-no-text .btn-kebab-view)

Comment: Try `element.$("button[_ngcontent-c16='']").click();`

Comment: Sometimes, when the page has dynamic html OR your protractor navigation logic is "too fast" or "too slow" - you might be trying to find element before or after it actually exists on the page.

Comment: If my answer applicable for you -- check the tick near my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following CSS Selector: `.btn.btn-flat.btn-no-text.btn-kebab-view`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use XPath:

For the button:

```
//button[@class='btn btn-flat btn-no-text btn-kebab-view']
```

Or for the i tag:

```
//i[@class='zmdi zmdi-more-vert']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using class name locator:

```
by.className('btn btn-flat btn-no-text btn-kebab-view')
```

or you can use XPath:

```
//*[@class='btn btn-flat btn-no-text btn-kebab-view']
```